# Distinct rows using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have been trying to get this query to work from a long time!
**Table:**
ID  -  Base  -  Date
1  -   1991  -  2013-09-13
2  -   1992  -  2013-01-12
3  -   1990  -  2013-09-13
4  -   1998  -  2013-02-11

I want to get all the rows with distinct Dates. For eg:
**Required Output**
ID  -  Base  -  Date
1  -   1991  -  2013-09-13
2  -   1992  -  2013-01-12
4  -   1998  -  2013-02-11

What i have so far is displaying all the records and thats not what I want.
**My Code:**

```
public IEnumerable<tableName> GetAllRecords()
    {
        var records = _tableName.GetAll().GroupBy(tb => tb.Date).SelectMany(tb => tb.Distinct());

        return records;
    }
```

How do I get the required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<tableName> GetAllRecords() {
    var records = _tableName.GetAll()
                  .GroupBy(tb => tb.Date)
                  .Select(g=>g.First());
    return records;
}
```

**NOTE**: it's still unclear on what exactly what you want, we have the `Base` and `ID` parts of duplicated rows are **different**, so **you may have some criteria or rule to choose between them in a group of `Date`**.

Comment: Perfect! just had to replace First() with FirstOrDefault(). Thanks you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: nope all i had to do was get rid of rows with duplicate Dates. Your solution works well. Cheers.

Comment: @smons you don't need `FirstOrDefault()` here, because `First()` is always `successful`, the `Group` has always at least `1 element`.

Comment: If I use First() I get NotSupportedException. Error:The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: @smons looks like you `append` something after `First()`?